# Customizer on the rise - JS Acceptable?

Tags: discussion

With [Themes Requiring Customizer over Theme Options](http://wptavern.com/wordpress-org-now-requires-theme-authors-to-use-the-customizer-to-build-theme-options) I imagine we'll see a rise in JavaScript and customizer related questions. My question is, how tolerant should we be of JavaScript Questions?

Looking at the SE bounties I noticed this question:

[Understanding WordPress Customizer JS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119863/understanding-wordpress-customizer-js-api)

Would that be considered on-topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What is on-topic and what isn’t does not depend on the language. It can be PHP, JavaScript, CSS, XML or [Python](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120261/73).

The key question is: Do you need a WordPress developer to solve it?

If can you solve the problem without ever looking at the WordPress code and no knowledge about the required context, it is probably off-topic.

The question on SO requires someone who knows the JavaScript part of the built-in customizer, it is clearly on-topic here.